# How to upload more file type in php

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have some problem regarding to upload the file in PHP. In my coding user can upload only image jpeg/jpg only. I want user also can upload word (.doc , .txt) and image in (.png)

When I upload the image, the image not enter the database but enter the folder file name "upload". This is my code. Hope anyone can help me.Thank you.

```
<? include "conn.php";?>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $target = "uploads/"; 
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "doc");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]));
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    //Function to generate image thumbnails
    function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

        /* read the source image */
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        $width = imagesx($source_image);
        $height = imagesy($source_image);

        /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
        $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

        /* create a new, "virtual" image */
        $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

        /* copy source image at a resized size */
        imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

        /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination with 100% quality*/
        imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest,100);
    }

    //check for allowed extensions
    if (($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpg")|| ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/png")|| ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "word/doc")&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        $photoname = $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"];
        if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $photoname))
        {
            die( '<div class="error">Maaf <b>'. $photoname . '</b> telah dimuatnaik sebelum ini</div>');
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO updown (nama_file,tkh_muatnaik) VALUES ('$photoname','$date')";
            mysql_query($query); 
            $sql = "SELECT MAX(id_gambar) FROM updown";
            $max = mysql_query($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($max);
            $maxId = $row['MAX(id_gambar)'];

            $type = $_FILES["file_upload"]["type"];
            switch($type)
            {
                case "image/jpeg":
                $ext = ".jpeg";
                break;
                case "image/jpg";
                $ext = ".jpg";
                break;  
                case "image/png":
                $ext = ".png";
                break;
                case "word/doc":
                $ext = ".doc";
                break;      
            }

            //define arguments for the make_thumb function
            $source = "uploads/".$photoname;
            $destination = "thumbnails/thumb_". $maxId . $ext ."";          
            //specify your desired width for your thumbnails
            $width = "282";
            //Finally call the make_thumb function
            make_thumb($source,$destination,$width);

            $msg = '<div class="success">
                        <b>Muatnaik: </b>' . basename($photoname) . '<br />
                        <b>Format: </b>' . $_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] . '<br />
                        <b>Size: </b>' . ceil(($_FILES["file_upload"]["size"] / 1024)) . 'Kb<br />
                    </div>';
            }    
            else
            {
                $msg = '<div class="error">Maaf, muatnaik file tidak berjaya</div>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = '<div class="error">Format file ini tidak diterima!</div>';
        }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="js/jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">  
function redirectpage(){

    window.location = "daftar_majlis_1.php";
}   
<!--

</script>
<link href="css/style_galeri.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<table width="70%"  align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="header"></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="79%"><? include "menu_admin.htm"; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><H3 class="main_title">Muat Naik Gambar Disini</H3>(<a href="galeri_admin.php" >Lihat Galeri</a>)
<div id="upload">
<?php echo $msg; ?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">File:</label>
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="upload_file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</div></td>
    <td width="21%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have u copied your code from somewhere else??

Comment: This code from my friend i just post here to help him.

Comment: make use of MIME types.... so that you will get rid of this extension roblem... here is the link... http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in_array are case-sensitive. So try:

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "doc", "txt", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG", "DOC", "TXT");
```

Secondly, seems that correct MIME type for .doc document is 'application/msword'.

Try this:

```
//check for allowed extensions
if (($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpg")|| ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/png")|| ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "application/msword")&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
...
...
...
            //inside the switch
            case "application/msword":
            $ext = ".doc";
            break;
...
```

You also should make thumbs for image MIME types only.

```
     if (!in_array($ext, array('.doc', '.txt'))) {
        //define arguments for the make_thumb function
        $source = "uploads/".$photoname;
        $destination = "thumbnails/thumb_". $maxId . $ext ."";          
        //specify your desired width for your thumbnails
        $width = "282";
        //Finally call the make_thumb function
        make_thumb($source,$destination,$width);
     }
```

Comment: when I click file and choose Microsoft word, it still can not upload.

Comment: You need to provide additional info. Is upload started, print_r($_FILES), any errors or warnings.

Comment: Thank you everyone the problem solve, but when I used .docx for application/msword it does not work but if I used .doc it work. May I know why?  .docx is for Microsoft word 1997- 2003 document

Comment: Actualy .doc is Microsoft word 1997-2003 document extension. Also .docx have different mime type: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Comment: thank you V G for your explanation. If users want to upload ZIP and RAR files. What MIME types I should use. I already google & try it, but it does not work. 

.zip application/x-compressed
.zip application/x-zip-compressed
.zip application/zip
.zip multipart/x-zip


I refer at this site:  http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full

Comment: Try to upload your ZIP or RAR and see `var_dump($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"]);`

Comment: how and where to see the code var_dump($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"]);

Comment: V G - I get it. Thank you. But I did not use  var_dump($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"]);